# How can I remove a toilet brush that is deeply stuck in a shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, repair, shower

I was trying to clean my shower drain with a toilet brush and the toilet brush broke inside the pipe. Now, the head of the toilet brush is stuck about 2 feet down in the pipe. Water will not pass, the head is stuck.

*Any suggestions on how to pull this toilet brush head out?* I was thinking a toilet snake, but not sure it will even get past the brush head to pull it out from the underneath.

Comment: It might be time to call a plumber. If you have a snake, why were you using a toilet brush?

Comment: @Comintern I don't have a snake. I was thinking about going to buy one to try and get the brush head out. How would a plumber go about this? Anything I could try doing, anything at all?

Comment: My guess is that they'll have to run a snake down to it and try to get the spring tip or hook tangled with the head of the toilet brush enough that it will stay together long enough to pull it out.  Depending on the run of the pipe, you might be able to fish at it with a coat hanger with a hook bent onto the end.

Comment: Is the shower drain pipe enclosed in a floor, or can you access it from underneath (e.g. from a basement). Hopefully it won't be necessary to cut the pipe. Cutting/replacing the pipe itself would be easy enough, but access to the pipe could be destructive.

Comment: If you can access the drain from the outside. you can use your hosepipe (whilst on or off) to try to knock it out.. much depends on your drain config.. it will not bend corners...

Comment: How has no one asked... what the $#%! were you doing cleaning your shower with a toilet brush?

Comment: The drain is 2 inches in diameter. I was trying to clean it with the toilet brush as it looked like a perfect fit.

Comment: Called Roto Rooter. Plumber used a long drill to break the brush head in half, then used long pliers to grab each piece and pull it out. $450 big ones!

Answer (score 5):

Coathanger, cut into a wire, with a hook on the end might work.
Push the hooked end past the stuck brush, keeping the hook near the perimiter of the pipe.
Rotate the hanger 90° so the hook is under, and engages, the stuck toilet brush.
Pull up on the end of the coathanger with a pliers or vicegrips.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the type that's plastic use a long drill bit but slide a metal close hanger with a hooked end down its side first to hold it in place , know with your drill gently drill out the center to make a hole all the way thought so you can use your close hanger to to slide down the center and hook it. Once you have done this boil water get it very hot this will soften the brushes so it can slide out. If your close hang doesn't pull it up get a long needle nose pliers and grab it but boiling hot water is the trick to soften the brushes to get it out

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.